# Injecting InterfaceRepo into A service

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, backend

I have project with nestjs in my university. This is my first time using nest, so I have problem injecting the user repo into userService.

I created a base repo interface in `base.interface.repository.ts` which extends `Document`:

```
import { Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

export interface BaseInterfaceRepository<T extends Document> {
  create(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T>;

  findAll(): Promise<T[]>;

  findById(id: string): Promise<T | null>;

  update(id: string, data: Partial<T>): Promise<T | null>;

  delete(id: string): Promise<T|null>;
}
```

And I have an abstract class `base.abstract.repository`:

```
import { Model, Document, model, Error, Promise } from "mongoose";
import { BaseInterfaceRepository } from "./base.interface.repository";
import { filter } from "rxjs";

export abstract class BaseAbstractRepository<T extends Document> implements  BaseInterfaceRepository<any>{
  protected model: Model<T>;

  constructor(model: Model<T>) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  findAll(): Promise<any[]> {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }


  async create(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T> {
    return await this.model.create(data);
  }

  async findById(id: string): Promise<T | null> {
    return await this.model.findById(id).exec();
  }

  async findOne(filter: any): Promise<T | null> {
    return await this.model.findOne(filter).exec();
  }

  async find(filter: any): Promise<T[]> {
    return await this.model.find(filter).exec();
  }

  async update(id: string, data: Partial<T>): Promise<T | null> {
    return await this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, data, { new: true }).exec();
  }

  async delete(id: string): Promise<T|null> {
    const result = await this.model.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    return await result;
  }
}
```

This is my `user.repository.interface.ts`:

```
import { User } from 'src/Schema/User.Schema';
import { BaseInterfaceRepository } from "../../../repositories/Base/base.interface.repository";

export interface UserRepositoryInterface extends BaseInterfaceRepository<User> {
}
```

And I have `User.repository.ts` which extends `BaseAbstractRepository` and implements `UserRepositoryInterface`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { BaseAbstractRepository } from '../../../repositories/Base/base.abstract.repository';
import { User,  } from 'src/Schema/User.Schema';
import { UserRepositoryInterface } from "./user.repository.interface";


@Injectable()
export  class UserRepository extends BaseAbstractRepository<User> implements UserRepositoryInterface {

  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name)
              private readonly userModel: Model<User>,private repo:UserRepositoryInterface
  ) {
    super(userModel);
  }
}
```

The problem is when I try to inject `UserRepositoryInterface` into the `userService` - I get an error.

This is my `UserService`:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserRepositoryInterface } from "./UserRepo/user.repository.interface";
import { UserRepository } from "./UserRepo/user.repository";
import { User } from "../../Schema/User.Schema";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@Inject('UserRepositoryInterface') private readonly repo: UserRepositoryInterface) {}

}
```

I try add the provider of `userRepositoryInterface` in the `UserModule.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from "./user.service";
import { UsersController } from "../../Controllers/user.controller";
import { UserRepository } from "./UserRepo/user.repository";
import {UserRepositoryInterface} from "./UserRepo/user.repository.interface";

@Module({

imports:[],
  controllers: [UsersController],

  providers: [
    UserService,
    {
      provide: 'UserRepositoryInterface',
      useClass: UserRepository,
    },
  ]

})
export class UserModule {}
```

And I import the usermodel in the app model like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { MongoDataServiceModule } from './Config/Mongo/mongo-data-service.module';
import { UserService } from './uses-case/User/user.service';
import { UserModule } from './uses-case/User/user.module';
import { UserRepository } from "./uses-case/User";
import { BaseAbstractRepository } from './repositories/Base';
import {BaseInterfaceRepository} from "./repositories/Base";

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongoDataServiceModule,
    UserModule,
    ,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but it didn't work:

```
[Nest] 7576  - 02/14/2024, 10:03:05 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the AppModule instance.
The module at index [2] of the AppModule "imports" array is undefined.                                      

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [2] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope []
Error: Nest cannot create the AppModule instance.
The module at index [2] of the AppModule "imports" array is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s looks like you have something after UserModule in imports in AppModule. Try to delete line with comma only and let us know if it works.